# raw_input: I don't know why my python code doesn't work

Tags: python

I am fairly new to python and I attempted to make a code. I want you to enter the cost of your meal, then the tax of your area, then your tip.

```
meal=raw_input("What was the cost of your meal?")
tax=raw_input("What is the tax in your area?")
tip=raw_input("What will be your tip percentage?")
print meal*tax+tip
```

Comment: What's the error you are getting? And also, please specify a definitive title for your problem next time!

Comment: It says Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'

Comment: time to learn some debugging skills. But first how about checking the inputs to make sure they are in a valid format and range ? Your calculation doesn't make sense either

Comment: and also learn to mark an answer as accepted so it won't show up in unanswered section anymore.

Comment: Fyi, total cost does not equal meal*tax+tip, it is meal+tax+tip.

Answer (score 2):

raw_input returns a string.  You must cast your input values to numbers:

```
meal = float(raw_input("What was the cost of your meal?"))
tax = float(raw_input("What is the tax in your area?"))
tip = float(raw_input("What will be your tip percentage?"))
print(meal * tax + tip)
```

Comment: The last line doesn't compute - tip percentage

Comment: @lxx: the question was not about the math, which I have merely replicated from OP's code

Answer (score 0):

Better you check basic Python tutorials first. Because it's very basic, `raw_input` returns string. In other case it's a letter, remember that in Python `"4"` is different than `4`. First one is a string, second is a digit.

Since you didn't convert your variables to integer or float, you can't do math operations. Can you tell what is `a*b` or `a+b` ? No, so Python can't. As I said `"4"` is different than `4`, so you can't do an operation like `"4"+"4". It's equal to`a+b`.`raw_input returns string, you have to convert that variables integer or float first, then you will be able to do math operations.

```
meal = float(raw_input("What was the cost of your meal?"))
tax = float(raw_input("What is the tax in your area?"))
tip = float(raw_input("What will be your tip percentage?"))
print (meal * tax + tip)
#do your math operations
```